# How to configure a single gRpc channel when using multiple clients with AddCodeFirstGrpcClient

Tags: c#, grpc, blazor-webassembly, protobuf-net, protobuf-net.grpc

From what I understand, it's best to reuse gRPC channels. What is the right way to create multiple code-first clients which share address and handler configurations?

I have multiple ASP.NET gRPC services hosted at the same server/address. I want multiple clients to be configured in the same way and use to the single common channel. For example, I want to configure a `GrpcWebHandler` and a `DelegatingHandler` so I can use `SetBrowserRequestCredentials`. For context, I'm creating these clients in Blazor WebAssembly.

I'm also using the code-first approach with `protobuf-net.grpc`. But, all the documented examples I could find of `...Services.AddCodeFirstGrpcClient()` seem to provide an `Address` with each client. I assume this results in a separate channel created for each client.

Here is an example repo which I'd like to update with the correct approach.
https://github.com/vyrotek/blazor-wasm-codefirst-grpc/blob/main/Example/Client/Program.cs

Comment: There is more than one type authentication.  See : https://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth/  Most apps are moving toward OAUTH2 because it is supported on Windows, MAC, and Linux.  OAUTH uses tokens for authentication

Comment: @jdweng I don't see how your comment is relevant. I'm experienced with OAUTH2 and am intentionally avoiding it to avoid the unnecessary complexity.

Comment: Following may help https://www.learmoreseekmore.com/2022/04/blazorwasm-cookie-series-part-1-blazor-webassembly-cookie-authentication.html

Comment: You are doing an HTTP request and getting back an HTTP Response.   A HTTP client opens a new connection for each request and then gets back a response.  Then the connection is closed.  So when you have multiple clients you have multiple connections.  So you are not using a single common channel, you have multiple connections at the transport layer.  The application layer will have a common channel to serialize the data at the client and deserialize the data at server.  This may just be an issue of understanding the different network layers.

Answer (score 0):

From what I could find, this seems to be the next best option.

This approach drops `protobuf-net.Grpc.ClientFactory` and instead creates the services manually.

```
var baseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress);

builder.Services.AddSingleton(services =>
{
    var httpHandler = new CredentialHandler(new GrpcWebHandler(GrpcWebMode.GrpcWeb, new HttpClientHandler()));
    return GrpcChannel.ForAddress(baseAddress, new GrpcChannelOptions { HttpHandler = httpHandler });
});

builder.Services.AddScoped(services =>
{
    return services.GetRequiredService<GrpcChannel>().CreateGrpcService<IAuthService>();
});

builder.Services.AddScoped(services =>
{
    return services.GetRequiredService<GrpcChannel>().CreateGrpcService<IWeatherForecastService>();
});
```